# Unknown Python syntax in PyTorch: a instance can directly receive a parameter

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a question about Python syntax when I'm learning PyTorch. The following codes are an example from the PyTorch document.

```
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
input = autograd.Variable(torch.randn(128, 20))
output = m(input)
print(output.size())
```

This first line is to create an instance `m`, but why this instance `m` can directly receive a parameter like the line 3? I think it should use method to deal with parameter like `m.method(input)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, any object can define a `__call__` method that allows it to be used as a function like in your example.

Reference: [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**call**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not very familiar with Python, so I didn't know it before.

Comment: Glad I could help